# how to open an exe file from google chrome

Tags: uri

i had the following code

`<html>
<body>
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='windowsformapplication1:as%20hi'" value='Browse'>
</body>
</html>`

but iam not getting the exe file from google chrome

before this i added uri with name windowsformapplication1 see below

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/windowsformapplication1
  (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
  URL Protocol = ""
  DefaultIcon
     (Default) = "windowsformsapplication.exe,1"
  shell
     open
        command
           (Default) = "C:/Users/vembu/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" "%1"
```

then it is created uri but not coming in google chrome but coming in firefox please give me answer in advance thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all check which browser it is then we can easily write code for the corresponding browser.

for google chrome and mozilla we can use the following code .

`window.location= 'myproto://anything'`

for internet explorer we can directly open by using activeXobject.